# How to delete messages from mailbox older than a specified time in a local server

Tags: postfix, exim, mailbox

Some automatic processes, like those made at regular times using cron, generate a lot of messages. I would like to delete automatically those older than a month so my mailbox doesn't grow too much.

I tried with a bash script that archives the old messages and tries to delete them from the mailbox, but I get this message from the system:

```
Mailbox /var/spool/mail/username was modified or is in use now.
It's not safe to complete the operation...
```

I have the same problem with both exim and postfix (in different servers).

I guess I could do it simulating a local email client like mutt using bash or python but I am not sure how to do it. I am not interested in using maildir because there are thousands of small messages that are more manageable in a single mailbox.

This is a local server using mail spool and local clients. We are not using imap or sending messages outside the server.

I will appreciate any hints.

Comment: This isn't typically something for the MTA to handle. What MDA are you using?

Comment: Actually I am not using a MDA since the mail is local and mutt can read it directly from the spool.

Answer (score 1):

The `grepmail` command can do what you want. You may also be able to accomplish this using just the mail[x] command with some ingenuity. I would suggest something like:

```
mailx <<EOF
s 1-$ mbox
q
EOF

grepmail ...
```

This will save all messages in your system mailbox to a file called `mbox`. It will also delete those messages from your system mailbox. You can then run `grepmail` on the `mbox` file.

Comment: Thanks, the problem is that I need to do this automatically from a script. If I put your mailx commands in a bash script it doesn't recognize s as a command but as a syntax error , and fails.